# jQuery Cycle Slideshow stops workring with 3+ photos

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle, colorbox

I have a slide show with Previous and Next buttons that works fine with 3 `<li>`'s but once I add a Fourth (or more) the next button and previous button don't show up, and they don't work (even if they were invisible). Any ideas?

The Sample Page is:
http://newsite.702wedding.com/las-vegas-wedding-packages.aspx

using jQuery Colorbox and Cycle.

Please take a look and see what happening.

Comment: Lists** 3 Lists! sorry i used html < li >

Comment: You can show them with ` before and after, edited your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
$("#slideshow").hover(function() {
    $("ul#vig").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $("ul#vig").fadeOut();
});​
```

Set the `z-index` of `ul#vig` to something higher than 5, which is the same as the elements you need it to be on top of. I set it to 15 with developer tools and it's working fine for me now.